# Primefaces Datatable inside Tab when tabChange ajax method nullPointerexception

Tags: primefaces, datatable, nullpointerexception, tabview

i have a 1 datatable inside a tab and another tab with a other datatable in tabview element, but when the method onTabChange is execute the TabEvent.getTab is null wtf?!!! I have the next Code

```
<h:form id="frmTab">
        <p:tabView id="tabs" dynamic="true" cache="false">
          <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{controller.onTabChange}" update="one-content,two-content"/>
          <p:tab title="First Tab" id="first-tab">
            <h:panelGroup display="block" id="one-content">
               <p:dataTable value="${controller.detailTable1}" 
               </p:datatable>
            </h:panelGroup>
          </p:datatable>
          <p:tab title="Second Tab" id="two-tab">
            <h:panelGroup display="block" id="one-content">
               <p:dataTable value="${controller.detailTable2}" 
               </p:datatable>
            </h:panelGroup>
          </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
```

When the onTabChange method is fired,
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:59)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:881)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)

Comment: What PrimeFaces version and JSF implementation and version are you using?

Comment: I have 5.3 primefaces version with jsf 2.2.10. the ontabchange works fine when i remove the datatable.

Comment: This code can **never** run, it is invalid xhtml

Comment: Its a very simple example.